# Search Suggestions In Android

Tags: android, listview, search

i have done Search suggestions in android by using edittext and listview.

what i need exactly is in my activity there are so many buttons after the edittext, when i type  letters in edit text it will show the corresponding search in list view but buttons will be appearing after that listview.

my xml file looks like this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="after Edit Text"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i am getting output as

[image]

wat i need is my list of suggeations should not disturb any buttons in background after that searchable edit text,, any help will be appreciated

Comment: i think what u r looking for is an `AutoCompleteTextView`..

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this:: move the buttons before listView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="after Edit Text"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Button"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```